# Why I can't receive a live555 RTSP stream into a QVideoWidget?

Tags: qt, h.264, rtsp, rtp, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to stream a H.264 video stream from a live555 server to a client application that displays it using QVideoWidget on Windows (Qt 5.5)

Unfortunately, the QVideoWidget does not show anything (but it does show videos that start with http:// instead of rtsp://).

If I sniff the packets I can see that the server is returned a 405 Method not allowed:

```
GET /testStream HTTP/1.0
 Host: 172.19.217.147
 User-Agent: NSPlayer/12.00.7601.17514
 Accept: /
 Accept-Language: en-us, *;q=0.1
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 Pragma: xClientGuid=
 {3300AD50-2C39-46C0-AE0A-889398BAE808} 
Pragma: packet-pair-experiment=1
 Supported: com.microsoft.wm.srvppair, com.microsoft.wm.sswitch, com.microsoft.wm.startupprofile, com.microsoft.wm.predstrm
 Pragma: no-cache,stream-time=0,stream-offset=0:0,packet-num=4294967295,max-duration=0
 Pragma: LinkBW=2147483647, rate=1.000, AccelDuration=10000, AccelBW=2147483647

HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
 Date: Tue, Oct 06 2015 13:35:55 GMT
```

I am using live555 testH264VideoStreamer to stream the video.
If I try to use libVLC then it works. Why is it not working with QVideoWidget (which in turn uses Windows Media Foundation)?

Comment: Is this RTSP over HTTP or plain RTSP? In case of second there should never be a GET command. How does the libVLC traffic look like?

Comment: The libVLC traffic looks normal, no HTTP GET methods. But the RTSP when using QVideoWidget is extremelly weird and includes HTTP inside RTSP:

Comment: `Real Time Streaming Protocol
    GET /testStream HTTP/1.1
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Pragma: getIfoFileURI.dlna.org
    Accept: */*
    User-Agent: NSPlayer/12.00.7601.17514 WMFSDK/12.00.7601.17514
    GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG: 1
    Host: 192.168.56.1:8554`

Comment: Is it mentioned anywhere that qt actually supports RTSP?

Comment: No, I can't find anything in the documentation. I guess we just assumed it would.

Comment: Well I think you have to combine qt with either live555, ffmpeg or either write your own plugin (which woul actually make most sense if so far you have been using plain qt).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Windows Media Foundation does not support many 3rd party RSTP streams which have slightly different headers and capabilities.

"The MF RTSP source has not been widely tested with third party RTSP servers." https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4ac87f5f-b8c5-471a-a424-55c0fff04eac/using-the-media-foundation-sdk-to-parse-rtsp-streams?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment

In the context of RTSP, "Media Foundation supports the following formats: WMA, WMV, audio/L16 (LPCM), and audio/MPA (MP3). The server's response should indicate which format it is asking for." https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/e1a970aa-8bf5-46bb-a301-de271a6ae4bc/rtsp-without-proprietary-supported-header?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment

Apparently, a custom WMF media source would need to be implemented and it may have differences depending on the quirks of the RTSP device.